# Load controller after $http request

Tags: ajax, angularjs, controller

I'm using a $http request like this:

```
$http({   
    method: 'POST', 
    url: url,
    data : {'some':'data'},
}).
success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
     container.css({    opacity : '0.0' }).html(  data  ).delay(50).animate({   opacity : '1.0' }, 300);
})
```

The $http response begins like this:
`<div class="tree" ng-controller="systemDataTree"><ul><li>`
Everything is loading as it should, I don't want to use routes. 
The content that is loading will have a `ng-controller="myController"` in it, but it does not execute after loading.

How do I get it to execute the controller loaded with the HTML response? 
I don't want to execute the controller inside the `$http.success` because there will be many different controllers used

Answer (score 0):

please correct me if wrong: you want a second controller to run after the response has come from the web service? correct?

for this you can move your template into ng-template

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="innerTemplate">
   <div ng-controller="myFirstCtrl">
</div>

</script>
```

in your main view you can  have such a

```
<div ng-controller="controllerWhichCallsHttp">
 your html here

 <div ng-include="variable"></div>
</div>
```

controllerWhichCallsHttp will have the following $http

```
$http({   
method: 'POST', 
url: url,
data : {'some':'data'},

}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

 $scope.variable="innerTemplate";  //i.e. after you get the response set the value of the variable with the id of the template and then myFirstCtrl will execute
 container.css({    opacity : '0.0' }).html(  data  ).delay(50).animate({   opacity :    '1.0' }, 300);
})
```

Comment: After a $http request we get pure HTML with first `<div ng-controller="someController">` which doesn't run. whatever I do, it's not running the controller

Comment: please vote up so everyone has the solution. it's yet another simple thing that Angular is supposed to do itself

Comment: @Pian0_M4n please be clear are you getting the html from a web service in response?
in that case do

$scope.exp=$compile("<div ng-controller="someController">")($scope);
element.append($scope.exp);

Comment: @Pian0_M4n i did a typo by  writing ng-template as ng-remplate have corrected it please verify

Answer (score 0):

DONE ::

here is the solution:

```
success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
     container.css({    opacity : '0.0' }).html(  data  ).delay(50).animate({   opacity : '1.0' }, 300);
})
```

instead of appending pure `data` use `$compile(data)($scope)` and you can add any number of controllers inside. 
Like this you can custom load your stuff and use controllers as you wish